# override values of a property from base class in C#

Tags: c#, properties, overriding

I have class A that inherits from class B, class B has a property like this

```
public configObject config
{
    get
    {
        var config = new configObject
        {
            property1 = value1
            property2 = value2;
            property3 = null
            property4 = false;
        };

        return config;
    }

    set { this.config = value; }
}
```

In class A, I am trying to override values of some fields of this.config but for some reason the values are not getting updates with the assignments in A

```
Public class A: B
{
    public A()
    {
    }

    public configJson
    {
         get
            {
                this.config.property2 = newValue2;
                this.config.property3 = newValue;
                this.config.property4 = true;
                return this.SerializeConfiguration(this.config);
            }
    }
}
```

Any idea where I am making a mistake? Appreciate any help!

Comment: Looks like the configObject is always returning a new object any value you set in A is overridden.  The get needs to return the value that the set updates.  Use a backing variable for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR: The best option is rewriting the `get` method of class B to reuse the same object rather than recreating it every time.**

This is being caused by the `get` method from your parent class. You can get around this in the child class if you do it as follows:

```
public configJson
{
     get
        {
            configObject cfg = new configObject();
            cfg.property1 = this.config.property1;
            cfg.property2 = newValue2;
            cfg.property3 = newValue;
            cfg.property4 = true;
            return this.SerializeConfiguration(cfg);
        }
}
```

Here's why it's a problem:

Every time that you use `this.config`, it calls:

```
get
{
    var config = new configObject
    {
        property1 = value1
        property2 = value2;
        property3 = null
        property4 = false;
    };

    return config;
}
```

Which means that the object is recreated every time.

I would recommend rewriting your parent class so you don't instantiate the values in the `get` method.

A quick way to do that is this:

```
class B {
    private configObject cfg;
    public configObject config {
        get {
             if (cfg == null)
                 cfg = new configObject
                 {
                     property1 = value1
                     property2 = value2;
                     property3 = null
                     property4 = false;
                 };

                 return cfg;
             }
         set { cfg = value; }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response, is there any way I don't need to reassign all values from Class B in Class A? the reason is there are about 40 fields inside this object and only 4,5 of them need to be overridden in class A

Comment: If you modify class B in the manner shown above, then you won't have to change anything in class A.

Comment: As long as you avoid recreating the object every time the `get` method is called, you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can override properties with the `new` operator. Lets say you have class `B`:

```
public class B
{
    public configObject config
    {
        get
        {
            var config = new configObject
            {
                property1 = value1
                property2 = value2;
                property3 = null
                property4 = false;
            };

            return config;
        }

        set { this.config = value; }  //This is actually a StackOverflow error!
    }
}
```

And you override that with `A`:

```
public class A
{
    public new configObject config
    {
        get
        {
            var baseConfig = base.config;
            //Modify baseConfig properties here
            return baseConfig;
        }
        set { base.config = value; }
    }
}
```

So now you've overridden the values from the base class.